# How to make requests from an external server to localhost

Tags: javascript, request

Is there a way that I can make a `GET` request from an external server (like `google apps script`) to my local server?

For example, I would like to make a `GET` request on this url: `http://localhost:3000/api/get_data`

If I do that then I get `DNS error`. Replacing `localhost` with my ip address gives `Bad Request`

Comment: Have you tried `https`? Also, what is the HTTP(S) status code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "localhost" address is not accessible from the Internet, so you can't use it.
Having your IP instead of "localhost" may work, that depends on the firewall rules of your ISP and on your local machine.

The easy way to expose your local machine to internet is either by using SSH (if you have the remote machine that is accessible from Internet, for example, Amazon EC2 instance). You can use `-R` ssh switch for that, something like this `ssh -R *:8181:localhost:3000 remote-machine` and you can use "http://remote-machine:8181" to connect to your app.
See also [The Black Magic Of SSH / SSH Can Do That?](https://vimeo.com/54505525).

Another way is to use service like https://ngrok.com/ that will do the remote part for you.